# How to write data from an external API to DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I want to get real-time data from a stock API (IEX API) and load it to DynamoDB. Most of the tutorials I've watched so far (like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJvfcg9dW4U&t=7s) around 15:10) show how to create Lambda functions and integrate with API gateway. However, they are still manually entering the data to load to the table. How do I use the API Gateway and Lambda to get data from the IEX API and load it to DynamoDB rather than writing the data myself?

Following some tutorials, my Lambda function for loading data to the table is:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    
    let responseBody = "";
    let statusCode = 0;
    
    const { id, stocksymbol} = JSON.parse(event.body);
    
    const params = {
        TableName: "StockData",
        Item: {
            id: id,
            stocksymbol: stocksymbol
        }
    };
    
    try {
        const data = await documentClient.put(params).promise();
        responseBody = JSON.stringify(data);
        statusCode = 201;
        
    } catch(err) {
        responseBody = `Unable to put item: ${err}`;
        statusCode = 403;
    }
    
    const response = {
        statusCode: statusCode,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: responseBody
    };
    
    return response
};
```

I would be getting more data from the API (opening price, closing price etc.) but this is what I have for now.

Comment: How often you are planing to call  IEX API?

Comment: if no obvious aim for mirroring the stock data into dynamodb, I would prefer direct request to lambda without api gateway in some interval. So the data is referencing lively. I'm doing this approach for other case on my shop transaction with Paypal API through lambda

Comment: @BaluVyamajala Just when the user loads the page

Comment: @MahdiRidho I want to store the data in DynamoDB because it will be used later on for analysis with AI. Right now, I want to load the data to DynamoDB and then get the data in the database and display it on the site.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need to utilize pull mechanism (you need to get data from API yourself), you can use AWS EventBridge rule to trigger your lambda periodically with interval of your preference - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/create-eventbridge-scheduled-rule.html. In lambda you download the API data and store them in DynamoDb.

If you can use push mechanism (you can get data pushed to you, e.g. https://iexcloud.io/docs/api/?gclid=CjwKCAiA_9r_BRBZEiwAHZ_v17o9kJuPyF5Do_E3_mwC0uHEh2yXqqOdtVgqvc34yEk5RR8W8028HRoC0HUQAvD_BwE#webhooks), you can set the your API gateway resource URL as a target path, while having your lambda function as the handler for the API Gateway resource URL, storing the pushed data to the DynamoDb.

Comment: Thanks! I will try out the push mechanism. I found this [AWS tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-step-by-step.html#api-gateway-create-resource-and-methods), do you think it would be helpful for my case? After uploading the data on DynamoDB, I would also like to grab it from the database and display it on the site.

Comment: To grab the data from dynamodb, you can follow this steps https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/